# Fastest way to find the closest destination

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is a network represented as two tables.
The P table has the source nodes and their coordinates.  There're about 8M records in this table.

```
PID     | x    | y     | ClosestG
XFEW134 | 30.3 | -20.1 |
ABCEFO1 | 10.1 | 1.1   |
```

The G table has the destination nodes (and their coordinates) associated with each P source node.  This table has about 24k.

```
PID     | GID |   x    | y
XFEW134 | 431 | -10.3  | -13.2
XFEW134 | 123 | 31.3   | -10.3
XFEW134 | 251 | 22.5   | 100.1
ABCEFO1 | 521 | 99     | -75.4
ABCEFO1 | 431 | -10.3  | -13.2
```

I want to find the fastest way to find the closest G node for each P and fill in the ClosestG field in the P table with the GID.  Thanks.

Comment: How would you calculate the distance? Its entirely possible, indeed likely, that there may be some ties. Like this? http://www.mathopenref.com/coorddist.html

Comment: Oh, I use the Pythagoras' Theorem for the coordinates between the P and G.

Comment: Every G has a PID. Are only those G's that belong to the same PID eligible? Or do you want to rule out any G's that belong to the same PID? Or something else?

Comment: Note that your test data, in the question is either, incorrectly denormalised or has a foriegn key constraint error. `GID` can't have an `x` of `10.3` and `-10.3`. Unless I suppose, `GID` is not a primary key and is just part of a compound key. Which is it?

Comment: @Jodrell You're correct.  I mistyped.  Same GiD should have the same coordinates.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Can't rule out anything. For each P, they're assigned to some G's and need to be taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this would work,

It calculates the magnitude of the distance from each `P` to each related `G`. Then selects only the `G` with the lowest magnitude.

Note that it is not necessary to use the `SQRT` function unless you actually want the distance.

```
WITH [ByDistance] AS 
(
SELECT
            P.[PId],
            G.[GId],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.[PId] ORDER BY
            (SQUARE(G.[x] - P.[x]) + 
                SQUARE(G.[y] - P.[y])) ASC) RowOrder
    FROM
            [P]
        JOIN
            [G] 
                ON G.[PId] = P.[PId]

)
SELECT
            P.[PId],
            P.[x],
            P.[y],
            D.[GId] [ClosetG]
    FROM 
            [ByDistance] D
       JOIN
            [P]
               ON P.[PId] = D.[PId]
    WHERE
            RowOrder = 1;
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecdfe/1)

Example output: (From your test data)

```
PID     X    Y     CLOSETG 
ABCEFO1 10.1 1.1   431 
XFEW134 30.3 -20.1 123
```

Comment: My current query using two joins takes over 8 hours to run while I only have about an hr or two hr window.  I'm going to test yours out and let you know the result.